Not Able to use the keyboard on Android 14
Android application type
Xamarin.Forms application
Xamarin.Android application
Affected platform version
Android 14 Emulator (pixel 7 pro)
enter image description here
Un affected platforms tested
Android 13 emulator(pixel 5), Android 9 emulator(pixel 2), Android 14 Device (Samsung s21fe), Android 13 device (S20fe).
Description: When using the Edit text on the alert dialog box, opening the alert dialog box 2nd time makes the built-in keyboard unusable
Steps to Reproduce:
1. Open the application AlertDialogIssue.zip
2. Press open dialog
3. Enter any text in Edit text and press OK
4. Now the keyboard is visible but we were unable to interact with the keyboard
We have created a custom alert dialog with the following codes
CustomAlertDialog.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/contentview"
        android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textinputlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordedit"
                android:hint="Edit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:password="true"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/errorview"
                android:text="Error"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/footerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="-15dp">
                        <Button
                                android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
                                android:text="Cancel"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:textColor="#0080eb"/>
                        <Button
                                android:id="@+id/okbutton"
                                android:text="Ok"
                                android:layout_width="70dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                
                />
        </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>

CustomAlertDialog.cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AlertDialogIssue
{
    internal class CustomAlertDialog : LinearLayout, IDisposable
    {
        private Context mainContext;
        private LinearLayout contentView;
        private AlertDialog passwordDialog;
        private AlertDialog.Builder alertbuilderpassword;
        internal bool isPasswordDialogAppearing = false;
        private View currentView;
        private EditText passwordEdit;
        private Button okButton;
        private Button cancelButton;
        private TextView headerView;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        internal CustomAlertDialog(Context context)
          : base(context)
        {
            mainContext = context;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomAlertDialog, this, true);
            InflateView(view);
        }
        internal void InflateView(View view)
        {
            currentView = view;
            contentView = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.contentview);
            headerView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.headerView);
            passwordEdit = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.passwordedit);
            okButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.okbutton);
            cancelButton = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cancelbutton);
            InitializePasswordView();
            DisplayAlertDialog();
        }
        internal void InitializePasswordView()
        {
            passwordEdit.TextChanged += PasswordEdit_TextChanged;
            passwordEdit.KeyPress += PasswordEdit_KeyPress;
            okButton.Click += OkButton_Click;
            cancelButton.Click += CancelButton_Click;
        }
        internal void ShowPasswordInputDialog()
        {
            if (passwordDialog != null)
            {
                passwordDialog.Dismiss();
            }

            if (!isPasswordDialogAppearing)
            {
                passwordDialog.Show();
                isPasswordDialogAppearing = true;
            }
        }
        internal void DisplayAlertDialog()
        {
            alertbuilderpassword = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainContext);
            alertbuilderpassword.SetView(currentView);
            alertbuilderpassword.SetCancelable(false);
            passwordDialog = alertbuilderpassword.Create();
            passwordDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysVisible);
            passwordDialog.Window.SetLayout(400, 400);
        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            passwordDialog.Dismiss();
            isPasswordDialogAppearing = false;
        }

        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            passwordDialog.Dismiss();
            passwordDialog.Show();
            passwordEdit.SetSelectAllOnFocus(true);

            passwordEdit.SetSelection(passwordEdit.Length());
            passwordEdit.SelectAll();
        }

        private void PasswordEdit_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
            {
                passwordDialog.Dismiss();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back)
            {
                passwordDialog.Dismiss();
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Del)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordEdit.Text))
                {
                    string tempString = passwordEdit.Text;
                    if (passwordEdit.HasSelection)
                    {
                        passwordEdit.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        passwordEdit.Text = tempString.Remove(tempString.Length - 1);
                        int position = passwordEdit.Length();
                        passwordEdit.SetSelection(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void PasswordEdit_TextChanged(object sender, global::Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                okButton.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}

We are invoking the custom alert dialog on the main activity using the following code
customAlertDialog.ShowPasswordInputDialog();
Did you find any workaround?
No, but with removing the passwordDialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateAlwaysVisible); in the DisplayAlertDialog method, it will not cause this issue, and it will not invoke the keyboard every time the dialog box is opened again.
I have issue on certain device on certain Android version only so need different solution for opening and closing the Alert dialog with Edit text or we need to way to report this bug as Xamarin and MS Question and answer denied this as their issue.

I tested on an Android emulator(Pixel 5-API 34), and I couldn't reproduce this problem.

Hi, I could replicate the issue only in debug mode tested with the same configuration. If you are checking on release mode could you check on debug mode? Also, check the gif for the complete replication procedure. Pressing cancel will not replicate the issue.

Yes, I tested in debug mode, but I could produce this problem on my Android emulator(Pixel 5-API 34).

could you please try this on Pixel 7 pro emlulator

Hi @ManojSF3414, I tried to on Pixel 7 pro emulator in debug mode on my side, but I still can't reproduce the problem.

Hi, @JessieZhang-MSFT are you using the same sample with the emulator that was created by Android Device Manager by Microsoft? Could you please confirm whether this issue occurred in this situation

Yes, it was tested in the scenario you mentioned.
